# content doesnot appear on pages which are inside other folders

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I created slider on masterpage, the images of the slider are inside "slider images" folder. my default page is naked in the solution explorer. so the slider works fine there. but my "About US" page is inside new folder and the problem is the slider doesnot show images on the about us page. can anyone help please..[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Comment: I am assuming you're missing this "../" in the image url of your About Us page. That being said, can you please post the url of one of your images that you're using in default as well as About Us pages.

Comment: <img src="slider images/02.jpg" alt="Image is Broken"/>

Comment: it is not in the about us page but in the master page.

Comment: Rename 'slider images' folder to 'slider_images' and as src '<img src="slider_images/02.jpg" alt="Image is Broken"/>'. It could be the problem.

Comment: Use ~ to point back to the root folder
 
<img src="~/slider images/02.jpg" alt="Image is Broken"/>

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the **~** to point back to the root folder or make use of the .net ResolveClientUrl

```
<img src="~/slider images/02.jpg" alt="Image is Broken"/>
```

OR

```
<img src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("slider images/02.jpg")%>' alt="Image is Broken"/>
```

And if possible then remove the space from the name of the folder.

Comment: still the same problem no effects